# Directly connect phone land line to laptop to act as an ADSL modem

Tags: modem, adsl, adsl-router, pppoe, rj-11

I have a laptop which has an rj11 port (LSI HDA Modem). Is it possible that I  could directly connect the phone line (which has an adsl subscription on it) to the laptop so that the laptop could act as an adsl router? Or would that require a specific software?

**note:** the actual adsl router uses PPPoE connection to connect to the ISP

Comment: I edited the question to make it a little more clear. The asking for software may or may not be on-topic, this stuff isn't my forte, so I'm not sure if this is a hardware question or a software request.

Comment: A 56k modem (your laptop) will not be able to communicate with the ADSL device on the other end of your phone line. I would be surprised if your laptop has an ADSL modem fitted. You need not only special software, but special hardware too.

Comment: Not possible. An ASDL modem is a **specialised** modem. Why can't you just use your ISP supplied modem?